# find first and last row of database table mysql in a single select without using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I need first and last row of a db table in a single SQL query without using UNION operator. I have a solution but i need more efficient solution.

I want to select city with Minimum and Maximum length

```
 (select city, length(city) from country order by length(city) ASC, city ASC limit 1 )
 UNION ALL 
 (select city, length(city) from country order by length(city) DESC,city ASC limit 1)
```

Comment: What you wrote is what I would have done.  What is wrong with your query?

Comment: I want to know that is there any way to this more efficiently i.e. without using UNION

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it without `UNION`. And unfortunately, `ORDER BY LENGTH` can't make use of indexes, so it will be slow.

Comment: You're using `UNION ALL` which is incredibly efficient. If this query is somehow slow or inefficient, that's not the cause. But without a clear problem and a clear goal, it's practically impossible to answer this question. So, can you explain why this query is not efficient enough for you?

Comment: @GolezTrol `ORDER BY LENGTH` has to do a full table scan and then sort all of it. If the table is large, this will be expensive. And doing it twice will be twice as expensive.

Comment: MySQL presumably isn't clever enough to realize that it can reuse the temporary table from the first sort and just go in the opposite direction for the second one.

Comment: On a sidenote: Why does a country table contain cities? Looks like a city table with a wrong name to me.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. The point I tried to make, is that OP is looking for an efficient replacement of the `UNION` operator while that in itself is not the issue, and it it unclear whether there is an issue at all (I mean, even a full table scan won't be slow with just a couple of hundred cities). For larger tables, the order by length would indeed become an issue, and your answer below solves that perfectly, while still keeping the union all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say: You are looking for the cities with the minimum and maximum length. These can be multiple cities per length, so you need a subquery. That can be done with `EXISTS` or with a join:

```
select c.city, length(c.city)
from country c
join 
(
  select
    min(length(city)) as min_length,
    max(length(city)) as max_length
  from country
) l on length(c.city) in (l.min_length, l.max_length)
order by length(c.city), c.city;
```

Comment: Your query works fine but if more than one row are returned for minimum or maximum, then we have to consider one of each ascended in alphabetical order. And your query is returning `Delhi 5,
Hisar 5,
Sirsa 5,
Kolkata 7`. and i needed `Delhi 5, Kolkata 7`

Comment: So you are not merely looking for the cities with the minimum and maximum length. The best approach for what you want is your original query with `UNION ALL` then or even Barmar's suggestion if you are ready to introduce a computed column in your table.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that ordering by `LENGTH` can't make use of indexes, so it has to scan the entire table.

If you're using MySQL 5.7 you can add a generated column holding `LENGTH(city)`, and then index that.

```
ALTER TABLE country ADD COLUMN city_len INT AS LENGTH(city) KEY;
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT city, city_len FROM country ORDER by city_len DESC, city LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT city, city_len FROM country ORDER by city_len ASC, city LIMIT 1;
```

The index on `city_len` will make this efficient.

Comment: A very good suggestion. One could even provide a covering index on `country(city_len, city)` to speed this up further.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work without using union, but I am not so sure if it makes any difference efficiency wise.

```
SELECT
    city,
    length (city)
FROM
    country c
WHERE
    c.city = (
        SELECT
            city
        FROM
            country
        ORDER BY
            length (city) ASC,
            city ASC limit 1
    )
OR c.city = (
    SELECT
        city
    FROM
        country
    ORDER BY
        length (city) DESC,
        city ASC limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select city,char_length(city) as length,if(char_length(city)=(SELECT max(char_length(city))   FROM sakila.city),'max',if(char_length(city)=(SELECT min(char_length(city))   FROM sakila.city),'min',"NA"))  as type from sakila.city where char_length(city) =
(SELECT max(char_length(city))   FROM sakila.city) or 
char_length(city) =
(SELECT min(char_length(city))   FROM sakila.city)  ;
```

Comment: OP wants to select the city names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since `union all` is efficient way for that you are looking. But, you may also do that via `subquery`

```
select city, length(city) min_max_length
from country
where length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from country) or 
      length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from country)
```

Comment: I think it should just be `HAVING length(city) = ...`

Comment: You also don't need the double nesting, just `SELECT MIN(length(city))`. And there's no need for `GROUP BY city`.

Comment: `GROUP BY` city doesn't make sense. You are not even using an aggregation function in your main query. Do you mean `DISTINCT`? But why would you expect city duplicates in the table? So remove the `GROUP BY` and change `HAVING` to `WHERE`. And why those double subqueries to get the min and max of length(city)? Why do you think you must first rertrieve all lengths in order to get the min or max of these? You can simply `select min(length(city))` right away. Correct your query and you'll see it's only half as long and much more readable then.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.len,T1.city FROM 
( SELECT city,CHAR_LENGTH(city)  as len FROM country ) AS T1
INNER JOIN
( SELECT MAX(len) AS max_length,MIN(len) AS min_length 
 FROM ( SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(city)  AS len FROM country ) AS T) AS T2
ON T1.len = T2.max_length OR T1.len=T2.min_length
ORDER BY T1.len ASC, T1.city ASC
```

Comment: I don't see the need for the first subquery. You can just use `FROM country ... ON LENGTH(city) IN (t2.max_length, t2.min_length)`